# What is the difference between Converged Network Adapter and Server Bypass Adapter?

Tags: networking, hardware

[Intel® Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X540-T2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58954/intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x540-t2.html)

[Intel® Ethernet Server Bypass Adapter X540-T2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/68677/intel-ethernet-server-bypass-adapter-x540-t2.html)

I've found an info on CNA but no info on Server Bypass Adapter. What is this? Which one is more advanced and have more feature than the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bypass adapter will allow traffic to flow from one port to another if the server failed, is shutdown, etc.  You would typically use this when the server is not an endpoint in your traffic flow -- such as an inline monitoring server, some proxy applications, etc.

Converged network adapters allow simultaneous use of normal data plus storage date (FCoE/iSCSI) on the same wire.

I wouldn't say either is more advanced or feature rich - just depends on your requirements.